# Output from calculation is messed in perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I'm trying to do some calculations on the columns of a tab delimited file using this perl one-liner:

```
perl -ape 'if (/^\d/) { s/$F[2]/$F[2]\/$F[4]/e && s/$F[3]/$F[3]\/$F[4]/e}' infile
```

the idea is to get A and B columns divided by C column

infile:

```
X       Y       A       B               C
5001    3       1.03333 0.652549        4215
6001    4       1.2     0.723137        4870
7001    2       1       0.807843        5153
8001    2       1       0.807843        5355
9001    2       1       0.807843        5389
10001   2       1       0.807843        4955
11001   7       1.7671  1.05573 4966
12001   17      8.18802 4.72554 5124
```

But the output is this:

```
X       Y       A       B               C
5001    3       0.000245155397390273    0.000154815895610913    4215
6001    4       0.000246406570841889    0.000148488090349076    4870
7000.000194061711624297 2       1       0.000156771395303707    5153
8000.000186741363211951 2       1       0.000150857703081232    5355
9000.000185563184264242 2       1       0.000149905919465578    5389
0.0002018163471241170001        2       1       0.000163035923309788    4955
11001   7       0.000355839710028192    0.000212591623036649    4966
12001   17      0.00159797423887588     0.000922236533957845    5124
```

What is going on on the 3rd to 6th lines? How can manage to fix this?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I removed the /e option from the substitute command and it seems that the calculation is being performed on the wrong column.

```
perl -ape 'if (/^\d/) { s/$F[2]/$F[2]\/$F[4]/ && s/$F[3]/$F[3]\/$F[4]/}' infile

X       Y       A       B               C
5001    3       1.03333/4215    0.652549/4215   4215
6001    4       1.2/4870        0.723137/4870   4870
7001/5153       2       1       0.807843/5153   5153
8001/5355       2       1       0.807843/5355   5355
9001/5389       2       1       0.807843/5389   5389
1/49550001      2       1       0.807843/4955   4955
11001   7       1.7671/4966     1.05573/4966    4966
12001   17      8.18802/5124    4.72554/5124    5124
13001   30      13.8763/5138    8.05385/5138    5138
```

Comment: how can I do this in a one liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After substitution and evaluation, you have something like `s/1/0.000194061711624297/`.  So the `s` operator looks for a `1` and finds it as part of the first column.  Whoops.  If we add some `\b` word-boundary markers, we can force the match part of the `s` operators to match a complete column, never just part of a column:

```
perl -ape 'if (/^\d/) { s/\b$F[2]\b/$F[2]\/$F[4]/e && s/\b$F[3]\b/$F[3]\/$F[4]/e}' infile
```

But that's still going to run into issues if it's possible for column `X` to equal column `A` or `B`.  Better to just do the calculations and then replace the entire line by assigning to `$_`:

```
perl -ape 'if (/^\d/) { $F[2] /= $F[4]; $F[3] /= $F[4]; $_ = join(" ", @F); }'
```

Use `sprintf` instead of `join` if you want a particular format to the output.

Comment: This is a very good spotting of the problem and further explanation. That was it.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that you are substituting the value that is in column 3 and 4 *whereever they appear in the whole line*.  For row 3, for example, you are doing `s/1/1\/5153/e` which affects the first occurrence of the digit `1` in the line, not necessarily the `1` that happens to be in column 3.

Try this:

```
perl -lane 'if ($F[4] =~ /[1-9]/) { $F[2] /= $F[4]; $F[3] /= $F[4] } print join "\t", @F' infile
```

If you want to limit the precision, do something like `$F[2] = sprintf "%f", $F[2]/$F[4]; ...`

Comment: affects the first occurrence of the digit 1, not every occurrence. There's no `/g`.